# Azure Text to Speech API Audio Output is Not Playing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, text-to-speech, azure-api-management, azure-speech

I'm new to Azure, and programming in general.

**BACKGROUND**

I'm building a Google Sheet App Script that sends the content of Sheet2!B1 to Azure Speech API and output the resulting voice to Sheet2!B2. However, despite using the `X-Microsoft-OutputFormat` as `riff-48khz-16bit-mono-pcm`, the output audio file doesn't play. I tried changing the output to `audio-24khz-160kbitrate-mono-mp3` based on the [answer I saw here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59151571/azure-cognitive-services-text-to-speech-and-audio-issue-in-ie-invalid-source) but it doesn't work either. I've tried changing the file type to .wav too, which didn't work too.

Here's the code. Can you suggest what I should do, please? Also, any tip on creating batch api requests is appreciated. Thank you.

```
function sendTextToAzureTTS() {
  // Azure Text to Speech endpoint and API key
  var endpoint = "https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1";
  var apiKey = "hidden";

  // Get the plain text from Sheet2 B1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var text = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  // Create the request payload
  var requestData = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/ssml+xml",
    headers: {
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": apiKey,
      "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat": "audio-24khz-160kbitrate-mono-mp3", // Use the supported format
    },
    payload: '<speak version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"><voice xml:lang="en-US" xml:gender="Female" name="en-US-EmmaNeural">' + text + '</voice></speak>',
  };

  // Make the POST request to Azure Text to Speech
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, requestData);

  // Check if the response was successful
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    // Get the audio data from the response
    var audioData = response.getBlob().getBytes();

    // Write the audio data to a file in Google Drive with the correct MIME type
    var audioFile = DriveApp.createFile('otuput_audio.mp3', audioData, "audio/mp3");

    // Get the URL of the created audio file
    var audioUrl = audioFile.getUrl();

    // Write the audio URL to Sheet2 B2
    sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(audioUrl);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error: " + response.getResponseCode() + " - " + response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

I tried to create azure speech post requests and get the audio file back via Google Sheet app script. However, the audio file is not playing. I expected a working audio file, but the audio file is not playing.

Answer (score 1):

I created speech service in azure portal.

[image]

I created a Google Spread Sheet and named it `TextToSpeech`. Add a trigger to the following Spread Sheet.

**Code:**

```
function sendTextToAzureTTS() {
  // Azure Text to Speech region and access key
  var region = "eastus"; // Replace with your Azure region
  var apiKey = "your-api-key"; // Replace with your Azure access key
  var endpoint = "your speech servive endpoint";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TextToSpeech");
  var text = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  var requestData = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/ssml+xml",
    headers: {
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": apiKey,
      "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat": "audio-24khz-160kbitrate-mono-mp3",
    },
    payload: '<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US"><voice name="en-US-AriaNeural">' + text + '</voice></speak>',
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, requestData);

  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {

    var audioData = response.getBlob().getBytes();
    var audioFile = DriveApp.createFile('output_audio.mp3', audioData, "audio/mpeg");
    var audioUrl = audioFile.getUrl();

    // Write the audio URL to the same sheet in cell B2
    sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(audioUrl);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error: " + response.getResponseCode() + " - " + response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

- The above code is placed in the script editor, and I added my Speech Service API key to the above code.
- I gave a text in cell B1, which I want to convert into audio.
- When I ran my script, it executed successfully.
  Then I was able to get the audio file URL in cell B2.

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pavan. I tried using your code as it is, but I still have the same issue. The original code executed too, but the output audio didn't play. Same thing for your code too. Did the audio play on your end?

Answer (score 1):

In your SSML code you use the the attribute xml:gender="Female" in the SSML.

This is an unknow attribute in Azure SSML and gives an error. I tested this

Pavan use in his example not the attibute Gender in his SSML code.

It's possible it's just this little thing and the other code is perfect?

Comment: I don't think so, Peter. the attribute is part of the sample request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech

"POST /cognitiveservices/v1 HTTP/1.1

X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm
Content-Type: application/ssml+xml
...
<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Male'
    name='en-US-ChristopherNeural'>
        I'm excited to try text to speech!
</voice></speak>"

I removed it from my code too and the output audio didn't play still. Pavan's code didn't play the output as well.

Comment: Do you receive an error code (Logger.log..) or do you have an  empthy MP3 file with zero length   or do you have an MP3 file, but you can't play it?

Comment: I have an MP3 file, but I can't play it. I don't receive an error code, and it's not an empty MP3 file.